# Objective-C Shared variables between classes

Tags: objective-c, class, variables

Basically I've implemented a connection method which parses a JSON from an URL, via sendAsynchronousRequest. Everything's working nicely. But at the end of the sendAsynchronousRequest function, I need to reload a tableView (since the data arrived and I need to show it).

Currently I'm doing it by sending the tableView as parameter to the function of the class that does the connection

```
@implementation WhosWhereConnection

- (void)setUpConnection:(UITableView *)tableView { 
... 
[tableView reloadData];
...
}
```

And calling the function with

```
[connection setUpConnection:self.tableView];
```

It's working as I intended, but I feel this ins't the most elegant way of doing it. What would you recommend?

Wish I could accept all your answers, thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to have a delegate method / block which is called on completion, or to post a notification (if multiple instances are interested in the event). This will allow you to break the dependency you currently have by making the actions performed as a result of the completion event anonymous to the `WhosWhereConnection` class. The simplest change will be to replace the table view parameter with a block.

---

Using a delegate requires the most code. The other answers show the code for the other options.

For delegation, we want:

1. A protocol to define method(s) that will be called
2. A property to hold the delegate object reference
3. Usage of the delegate
4. Implementation of the delegate method(s)

1, 2 & 3 are on `WhosWhereConnectionDelegate` class. 4 is on the table view controller.

1.

```
@protocol WhosWhereConnectionDelegate < NSObject >

- (void)connection:(WhosWhereConnectionDelegate *)connection didCompleteWithStatus:(BOOL)status;

@end
```

2.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id < WhosWhereConnectionDelegate > delegate;
```

3.

You don't show what `setUpConnection` does, but the delegate call should be made once the connection is complete.

```
- (void)setUpConnection { 
    BOOL status = NO;
    ... 
    // stuff here to process things and determine the status
    ...
    [self.delegate connection:self didCompleteWithStatus:status];
    ...
}
```

4.

The table view controller sets itself as the delegate of the connection before the connection starts.

```
 - (void)connection:(WhosWhereConnectionDelegate *)connection didCompleteWithStatus:(BOOL)status
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example in code please? I've been trying to implement a delegate for three days now, searching around but I don't seem to get the concept of it.

Comment: You specifically want a delegate? The answer from @LukasKukacka shows the block option which is, in some ways, simpler.

Comment: Well, I just want to learn how to write a delegate method, since I've been hearing that so much lately, but I still don't get it how it's done.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using blocks for this. It is convenient and very strong solution.

Something like this:

Method header (`.h` file)

```
- (void)setupConnectionWithCompletion:(void(^)())completionBlock;
```

Method implementation (`.m` file)

```
- (void)setupConnectionWithCompletion:(void(^)())completionBlock
{
    //  Do your stuff

    //  Call completion block (if set) when everything is done
    if(completionBlock) {
        completionBlock();
    }
}
```

And call it like this

```
[connection setupConnectionWithCompletion:^{
    [tableView reloadData];
}];
```

Comment: Oookay, and how do I declare the - (void)setupConnectionWithCompletion:(void(^)())completionBlock in the .h file? I've tried like 4 lines, non of them seem to be error-free.

Comment: Please see edited answer. Method declaration in header file is in fact the first line of implementation method ending with `;`

Answer (score 1):

`NSNotification`s is what you need.

```
- (void)setUpConnection{
   //... 
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notificationName" object:yourData];
   //...
}
```

In your viewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   //...
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dataDidLoad:) name:@"notificationName" object:nil];
   //...
}

 - (void)dataDidLoad:(NSNotification*)notification
{
   //do your stuff
   [tebleView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Yeey, least now I know how to do it with notification (been told I can also do it that way). Thanks